# libssh2.so.1.0.1 conflict in libssh2 install

Tags: rhel, rpm

I'm trying to install ssh2 for PHP in RHEL.

But it required libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm and libssh2-devel-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm.

So I downloaded and tried to install, I got below errors

```
# rpm -ivh libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm libssh2-devel-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 79ea5ed4: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1 from install of libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6_6.1.x86_64
```

The output of `yum info libssh2`

```
Installed Packages
Name        : libssh2
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.4.2
Release     : 1.el6_6.1
Size        : 318 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-x86_64-server-6
Summary     : A library implementing the SSH2 protocol
URL         : http://www.libssh2.org/
License     : BSD
Description : libssh2 is a library implementing the SSH2 protocol as defined by
            : Internet Drafts: SECSH-TRANS(22), SECSH-USERAUTH(25),
            : SECSH-CONNECTION(23), SECSH-ARCH(20), SECSH-FILEXFER(06)*,
            : SECSH-DHGEX(04), and SECSH-NUMBERS(10).

Available Packages
Name        : libssh2
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.4.2
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 124 k
Repo        : DVD
Summary     : A library implementing the SSH2 protocol
URL         : http://www.libssh2.org/
License     : BSD
Description : libssh2 is a library implementing the SSH2 protocol as defined by
            : Internet Drafts: SECSH-TRANS(22), SECSH-USERAUTH(25),
            : SECSH-CONNECTION(23), SECSH-ARCH(20), SECSH-FILEXFER(06)*,
            : SECSH-DHGEX(04), and SECSH-NUMBERS(10).
```

Could you help me on this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `yum info libssh2`

Comment: You should have used yum to install the package.  Yum would have resolved all the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to install two packages. With the installation of `libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm` you try to replace the file `/usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1`, which is also in the still installed package `libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6_6.1.x86_64`.

Use `--upgrade` to install a newer version:

```
rpm -ivh --upgrade libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm libssh2-devel-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

and also possible

```
yum install libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm libssh2-devel-1.4.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```